# AutoHotkey Not Starting At Boot

Tags: autohotkey

I have a shortcut to AHK in my Startup folder on a Windows 7 Ultimate x64 machine. Its been working just fine for years. Recently realized it no long loads at startup while everything else in the startup folder works. Once the machine has started, I can go to All Programs -> Startup and click on the AutoHotkey.ahk link and it starts fine.

I've checked Event Viewer and don't see anything there.  Even added an exception in my AV, Malware Bytes and Windows Defender which I've never had to do in the past on any PC.  I don't remember making any changes on this machine such as a new program install/uninstall.

Any ideas as to what is happening here? I posted this question on the AHK forum but everything suggested there has already been covered.

Thank you

Comment: For me (On Windows 10) the folder `shell:startup` (type that into Run or explorer address bar) works well. Not sure if we're talking about the same folder, if not, give it a try I guess. You can place either your script or a shortcut for it in there.

Comment: Yes, its always been that folder.  The shell:startup takes you to "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup".  I've always had a shortcut to my ahk file there.